# Using a Pandoc Lua filter, how can I tag each HTML div's custom style as a LaTeX environment?

Tags: filter, lua, latex, pandoc

I'm trying to create a Pandoc Lua filter to tag each div in an HTML document as a LaTeX environment, based on the div's "custom-style". I can do it like this if I specify the value of the "custom-style" (for example, "TEST"):

```
function Div(elem)
    if (elem.tag == 'Div') and (elem.attributes['custom-style'] == "TEST") then
      return {
        pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\begin{Test}'),
        elem,
        pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\end{Test}')
      }
    end
end
```

But I don't want to have to specify the value of the "custom-style". I want the filter to get the value from the div itself. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do, although this doesn't actually work, as I don't really know what I'm doing:

```
function Div(elem)
    if (elem.tag == 'Div') then
      return {
        pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\begin{'),
        elem.attributes['custom-style'],
        pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '}'),
        elem,
        pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\end{'),
        elem.attributes['custom-style'],
        pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '}')
      }
    end
end
```

The idea is that a div with the "custom-style" of "NiceStyle" would end up like this:

```
\begin{NiceStyle}
The text of the div goes here.
\end{NiceStyle}
```

A *different* div with the "custom-style" of "BADStyle" would end up like this:

```
\begin{BADStyle}
The text of the div goes here.
\end{BADStyle}
```

I really appreciate the help with this and would now like to ask about a possible refinement. If I have a custom style called "Chapter Title" in .docx, what Lua filter would I need to convert the styled text to a LaTeX \chapter? For example, let's say my chapter title is "My Great Chapter" and it's styled with the Chapter Title style. I would like it to appear in LaTeX as \chapter{My Great Chapter}.

I've tried to modify the Lua filter so kindly provided, but without success. Thanks for any help anyone is able to give for this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `if (elem.tag == 'Div') then` to

```
if elem.attributes['custom-style'] then
```

This ensures that the LaTeX block is created only if there's a custom-style present. The `elem.tag == 'Div'` test is redundant, as the function will only be called on `Div` elements by definition of how filter functions work.

The rest of the problems stem from confusions about the types, and which type is needed where. Here's a full solution:

```lua
function Div(elem)
  local style = elem.attributes['custom-style']
  if style then
    return {
      pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\begin{' .. style .. '}'),
      elem,
      pandoc.RawBlock('latex', '\\end{' .. style .. '}')
    }
  end
end
```